# Angular6: handleError can't read services injected?

Tags: typescript, angular6

it seems that i can't read a service injected inside the handleError function

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient, public _translate: TranslateService) { }        
login(user: User): Observable<User> {               
      console.log( this._translate); // I CAN READ THE SERVICE INJECTED    
      return this.http.post<User>("http://...../login",  params, httpOptions)
            .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));                  
}

private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {    
      console.log( this._translate); I CAN'T READ THE SERVICE INJECTED                           
      return throwError(error.error);                     
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are loosing `this` context using unbound function as argument in            `.pipe(catchError(this.handleError));`

it should be either

```
  .pipe(catchError(this.handleError.bind(this)));
```

or using arrow function

```
       .pipe(catchError((err)=>this.handleError(err)));
```